# I want to be able to shorten code in python, how can I do that?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot in python with discord.py. I want to know how i can shorten this function to fewer lines. This function takes a command (-cf red, for example) and flips a coin with both a red side and a blue side. When the results are in the code sends a DM to the person doing the coinflip while at the same time sending the results in the chat.

```
@bot.command(aliases=['coinflip'])
async def cf(ctx, *, cfchoice):
    cfResults = random.choice(['red','blue'])
    userId = ctx.message.author.id
    user = bot.get_user(userId)

    time.sleep(1)

    # If the user wins the coinflip
    if cfchoice == cfResults:
        # Send result in the channel
        await ctx.send(f'It is {cfResults}!')
        # Send a DM to the person
        await user.send('You won on coinflip! Well done.')

    # If the user loses the coinflip
    elif cfchoice != cfResults:
        # Send result in the channel
        await ctx.send(f'It is {cfResults}!')
        # Send a DM to the person
        await user.send('You lost on coinflip! Good luck next time.')
```

Comment: Why do you need it to be shorter?

Comment: You mean something like "remove the comments and blank lines"?

Comment: You can do `await ctx.author.send` directly, and skip getting the user by id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same line inside both branches of an `if`, that's a very good hint that you could just take it out of the `if` entirely.

```
@bot.command(aliases=['coinflip'])
async def cf(ctx, *, cfchoice):
    cfResults = random.choice(['red','blue'])
    userId = ctx.message.author.id
    user = bot.get_user(userId)

    time.sleep(1)

    await ctx.send(f'It is {cfResults}!')
    await user.send('You won on coinflip! Well done.' if cfchoice == cfResults else
                    'You lost on coinflip! Good luck next time.')
```

That said, **in general, this class of question is not on-topic on Stack Overflow.** You should ask about *specific problems*; "how can I make this shorter?", without an indication of which specific element you think is too verbose (and why you think that, and why making it shorter is in fact a *practical* thing to do -- as our rules limit the site to *practical*, answerable questions, and optimizing for terseness rather than readability or maintainability is often inherently impractical) is not specific.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why you would try to do that, the function looks pretty solid. Only thing you can do is change your 'elif' to 'else' as it will always get executed anyways if your if statement is not true. Also you should use snake_case and not camelCase for python due to naming conventions:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['coinflip'])
async def cf(ctx, *, cf_choice):
    cf_results = random.choice(['red','blue'])
    user_id = ctx.message.author.id
    user = bot.get_user(user_id)

    time.sleep(1)

    # If the user wins the coinflip
    if cf_choice == cf_results:
        # Send result in the channel
        await ctx.send(f'It is {cf_results}!')
        # Send a DM to the person
        await user.send('You won on coinflip! Well done.')

    # If the user loses the coinflip
    else:
        # Send result in the channel
        await ctx.send(f'It is {cf_results}!')
        # Send a DM to the person
        await user.send('You lost on coinflip! Good luck next time.')
```

Comment: Consider using the "Community Wiki" button (like I did on my answer) to not gain credit/rep for answering an obviously off-topic question. (Asking for general improvements rather than specific solutions to specific problems is more a fit for our sister site [codereview.se]).